# Configure OKTA MFA for React SPA

Tags: okta, multi-factor-authentication

I am trying to implement OKTA MFA (email) in React SPA. I have created a policy and rule and assigned it to a group but unable to receive the authentication MFA email.

I am using the OKTA Sign-In Widget and have an OKTA Developer account.

Below is the policy and rule configuration

[image]

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.